# How Can I avoid NullPointerException in FireBase auth?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

I have a nullPointerException at `id_user=userConnect.getUid();`when user is not logged,How Can I avoid this problem ? beacause I need to open activity even if id user is null.

```
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser userConnect = auth.getCurrentUser();
        id_user=userConnect.getUid();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (userConnect != null){
 id_user=userConnect.getUid();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The id of a user is NEVER null (the method `getUid()` is annotated with `@NonNull`) but the user can be null if no user is logged in, so you have to do this:

```
FirebaseUser userConnect = auth.getCurrentUser()
if (userConnect != null) {
  Intent i = new Intent(this, _Your_Login_Activity_.class);
  startActivity(i);
} else {
  String id_user = userConnect.getUid(); // NEVER NULL
  // ... 
}
```